# What is the expected return value of console.execute() on a SELECT operation

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm attempting to debug some code (not written by me) that uses a comparison on the return value of `cursor.execute()`:

```py
if db.cursor.execute(query) == 0:
```

I can't however find any confirmation of what the expected return value of `cursor.execute()` will be when it is running a `SELECT` operation.

The definition of the function states that the return value is the "number of affected rows", and all examples in the online documentation seem to show queries that make changes. Does a `SELECT` query affect rows such that it would return the number of rows found?

Comment: What's the actual query?

Comment: I can add it, although I don't feel it actually makes a difference. ```query = ("SELECT `id` FROM htdata.machine WHERE `machine_name` = '%s';" % self.MACHINE_NAME)```

Comment: I don't care what the query returns, I care what `cursor.execute()` returns

Comment: This is why I didn't want to share the query - it's an irrelevant distraction

Answer (score 0):

See [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

> Return values are not defined.

Use the other methods of the cursor object to work with the result:

- [`fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone)
- [`fetchmany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany)
- ...

Comment: To clarify, then, any code should not rely on the return value?

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyMySQL documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute)

> execute(query, args=None) Execute a query
>
> Parameters:    query (str) – Query to execute. args (tuple, list or
>   dict) – parameters used with query. (optional) Returns:    Number of
>   affected rows
>
> Return type:   int

`db.cursor.execute(query)` will return the amount of rows found with your query.